# Python is repeating

Tags: python, if-statement, command

I've started Python today, on a raspberry pi, and I wanted to create password protected menu. It all works except the options keep appearing after I enter an option.

This is my code can anyone tell me what is wrong with it please, I have kept it all here so you guys could see what is wrong. Like I said I get the first one, shutdown or items but when I enter 1 or 2 it repeats it, ignoring the `if` statement.

```
ans = True

while ans:

    print("""

    1. Shutdown
    2. Items

    """)

    ans=input("Please enter a number: ")

    if ans == "1":
        exit()
    elif ans == "2":

        pa=input("Please Enter Password: ")

        if pa == "zombiekiller":

            print("""

            1. Pi password
            2. Return To Menu

            """)

        else:
                print("You Have Entered An Inccorect Password. Terminating Programm")
                import time
                time.sleep(1)
                exit()
```

Comment: What is `exit` defined as?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by defined as, like i said only started today so im really confused on spercific terms

Comment: The Python interactive interpreter does define `exit` as a function, but it is not available to general scripts (it'd give you a `NameError` instead).

Comment: I thought perhaps you had done something like `exit = sys.exit` or similar.

Comment: which sys.exit i would need to add import sys right? also i dont have nameerror appear so i dont know if im getting it

Comment: ok well it is working for the time being, used input not raw_input for my python version, just a quick question it is possible to completely close the program skipping the warning "do you want to kill program?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using python 2.7, `input` will try and interpret your input as a python expression, returning the number `1`, not the string `"1"`. Always use `raw_input` to get a string from the user.

In python 3, the old `input` has been removed, and the old `raw_input` has been renamed to `input`.

Comment: ohh im using 2.7 i belive thank you, i added raw_input instead or input but now it stops the python file and lets me type in the python shell without errors or anything

Comment: @StevenSharman: You're not giving enough information. Exactly what input do you give it, and what happens?

Comment: wait got it working, but it nows says want to kill program which im ok with at the time being thank you

Answer (score 2):

`exit` doesn't *do* anything. Just putting it, alone, on a line dereferences the name but doesn't invoke it. Perhaps you meant to call it?

```
exit()
```

To step out of a `while` loop you could also use `break`, which is a statement:

```
while True:
    print('Ending this loop')
    break
```

Comment: oh ok, thanks  but it still doesn't change from the options nor does it exit the file

Comment: i can give this a go but i wasnt awear of adding a loop

Comment: @StevenSharman: You have `while ans:` at the top of your script. :-)

Comment: yeah, i changed it to true and it made an error, i used input not raw_input due to my python version

Comment: Right; then there were *two* problems. :-)